# How we design 3d column chart in highcharts like in pic?

Tags: highcharts, angular8

I want to design a chart as in pic in angular 8 highcharts.

I am able to design it in 2d. But i want it in 3d.

Can anyone give me a hint

[image: Image is for demo]

My code for this is:

```
this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        // renderTo: "container",
        type: "column",
        options3d: {
          enabled: true,
          alpha: 20,
          beta: 30,
          depth: 200,
          viewDistance: 5,
          frame: {
            bottom: {
              size: 1,
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      credits: {
        enabled:false
      },
      title: {
        text: "Trainee vs Webinar Chart"
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "Test options by dragging the sliders below"
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        gridLineWidth: 3,
        gridLineColor: 'green'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories:['Trainee','Webinar'],
        // min: 0,
        // max: 2,
        gridLineWidth: 0
      },
      zAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        categories: ['Trainee','Webinar'],
        labels: {
          y: 5,
          rotation: 18
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          groupZPadding: 10,
          depth: 60,
          groupPadding: 0,
          grouping: false,
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          // name: "Trainee vs Webinar Data",
          data: [
            {name:"Trainee",y:80,color:'#4472c5'},
            {name:"Webinar",y:60,color:'violet'}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am calling a function in ngoninit.

In that function I am defining this config for chart.

What is my mistake in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `highcharts-3d` module, in angular:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d';

HC_3d(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0qdkhbt6/

**Docs:**

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module